# Start same animation for diffrent objects one after another in android

Tags: android

I want to start same animation for some buttons,but i don't want to start in same time i want start one after another! i used this but it doesn't work!how can i fix this?
help me please

```
pivate void animation(){
    Animation fadein= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadein_btn);
    try{
        btn_seasons.startAnimation(fadein);
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return;
    }
    try{
        btn_main_exit.startAnimation(fadein);
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return;
    }
    try{
        btn_main_about.startAnimation(fadein);
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return;
    }
    try{
        btn_main_send.startAnimation(fadein);
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return;
    }
}
```

* i call my animation method on my onCreate method!

Answer (score 0):

lets asumme that you have layout something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will animate buttons with 90ms delay one after another with scale animation , starting delay is 800ms. if you want to animate only some of those buttons you will need to modify code a bit to suit your own needs. It's just an example to give you some idea.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   final LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

    int delay;
    for (int i = 0; i < linear.getChildCount(); i++) {
        delay=(i*90)+800;
        View v = linear.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof Button) {
            linear.getChildAt(i).setScaleY(0f);
            linear.getChildAt(i).setScaleX(0f);
            linear.getChildAt(i).animate()
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.6f))
                    .setStartDelay(delay)
                    .setDuration(400)
                    .scaleY(1f)
                    .scaleX(1f)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    })
                    .start();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AnimatorSet to start each animation after another: [Choreographing Multiple Animations with AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#choreography)